# Précisions du sens de « vin biodynamique » et de l'emploi de prépositions ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, prépositions, adjectifs

J'ai [entendu](https://youtu.be/6Ju96xJAjJI) l'expression « vin biodynamique », l'« [agriculture biodynamique](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26511899) » étant une « méthode d'agriculture [biologique](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870966) qui tient compte de l'action des cycles et des phénomènes naturels sur les organismes vivants » (GDT) mais comme j'ai de la difficulté à concevoir une production viticole indépendamment des cycles et du climat (*saison des [vendange](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/vendange)s* etc.) et que le rangement du terme sous *biologique* implique déjà qu'il n'y ait pas d'emploi de produits chimiques etc., peut-on en préciser le sens et expliquer, vu que [*biodynamique*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8413076) peut aussi être un nom, si l'on retrouve parfois les prépositions *de/en* entre *vin* et *biodynamique* ou si c'est exclusivement formé comme avec (produit) *biologique* ?

Comment: L'agriculture biodynamique se base sur des fondements purement ésotériques ([wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agriculture_biodynamique) utilise même le mot "magique" ^^), je pense qu'on peut dire en étant assez confiant que ça veut rien dire. Il n'y rien à expliquer, le créateur a juste choisi un mot un peu "compliqué" pour se donner du crédit.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Le fait que l'efficacité d'une approche ne soit pas démontrée ne signifie pas que le terme ne veuille rien dire de précis, comme le démontre l'existence de l'article Wikipédia auquel tu réfères. D'autre part le film auquel réfère le clip est présenté dans le cadre d'une [exposition](https://www.laciteduvin.com/fr/faire/expositions-temporaires/renversant-quand-art-design-semparent-du-verre) de _La Cité du Vin de Bordeaux_. C'est la langue qui m'intéresse, pas ton opinion.

Comment: Je comprends, quand l'étymologie et le sens n'a aucun lien avec la véracité du sujet, très bien, mais quand le sujet n'a aucune base, ça ne mène a rien d'essayer de comprendre son origine. Prenez les "[ondes scalaires](https://www.alternativesante.fr/ondes-scalaires/les-ondes-scalaires-medecine-de-demain)" par exemple. Pourquoi "scalaires", alors qu'elles sont en spirale ? Sur quelle base peut-on parler de "rayonnement" ? Si ce ne sont pas des ondes électromagnétiques, qu'est-ce que c'est ? On ne peut pas répondre à ces question car le "domaine" entier est basé sur du vent.

Comment: Et c'est dommage d'avoir à donner son opinion sur la crédibilité du sujet, mais on doit passer par là pour pouvoir dire qu'on ne peut pas répondre à la question.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Qu'elles soient farfelues et non étayées, il y a des bases tout de même. Note de plus qu'un [règlement de l'UE](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/FR/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32007R0834&from=FR) autorise directement l'emploi de _préparations biodynamiques_ (art. 12 c). Il ne les ignore pas sous prétexte que leur efficacité ne saurait être démontrée. Il ne s'agit d'un site sur la science mais bien sur la langue, il s'agit de distinguer l'agriculture biologique de celle qui serait biodynamique et les pratiques diffèrent indépendamment de leur base. On peut répondre et avertir.

Answer (score 1):

L'[agriculture biodynamique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agriculture_biodynamique) est « un système de production agricole magique issu du courant ésotérique de l'anthroposophie [basé sur les idées de Rudolf Steiner] » (Wikipédia, article identifié [en commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34326/pr%C3%A9cisions-du-sens-de-vin-biodynamique-et-de-lemploi-de-pr%C3%A9positions#comment70323_34326)) qui est ultra-minoritaire en agriculture ([0,1 %](https://www.agriculture-environnement.fr/2018/11/19/lagriculture-biodynamique-est-une-alternative-serieuse-baliverne-20)) et qui respecte souvent les principes de base de l'[agriculture biologique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agriculture_biologique) d'où la difficulté d'en distinguer les résultats. La [viticulture biodynamique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viticulture_biodynamique) s'appuie sur ces idées, d'où le produit dit « [vin biodynamique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vin_biodynamique) ». On n'a pas trouvé d'emploi avec une préposition.

L'agriculture qui en découle « mobilise notamment des savoirs sensibles basés sur l'observation, l'intuition et l'émotion, et fait appel à la pensée analogique » (Wikipédia), est teintée d'une vision anthropomorphiste de la ferme, s'appuie sur l'influence directe des astres et fait plus concrètement appel à l'emploi de [*préparations*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agriculture_biodynamique#Pr%C3%A9parations,_incin%C3%A9rations_et_autres_proc%C3%A9d%C3%A9s) bien particulières adossées à des notions de pseudo-science servant à « dynamiser » le compost/sol et qui ressemblent dans certains cas à des [solutions homéopathiques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viticulture_biodynamique#La_protection_des_cultures) ; la vinification fait parfois aussi appel à des procédés de cette autre pseudo-science (la [dynamisation](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dynamisation)).

À la différence de l'agriculture biologique (plus particulièrement la [viticulture biologique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viticulture_biologique), dont découlait anciennement le « [vin issu de la viticulture biologique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vin_issu_de_la_viticulture_biologique) », maintenant combinée à la vinification biologique et qui sont à l'origine du [*vin biologique*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vin_biologique)), qui a fait ses preuves en termes de pratiques (« qui se sont déjà révélés efficaces aussi bien sur la structure du sol, que sur la flore et la faune du sol ou bien encore sur le contrôle des maladies. Une efficacité qui est due tant aux ajouts des matières organiques qu'à la réduction de la densité du sol », [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viticulture_biodynamique#Le_syst%C3%A8me_agricole)) ainsi qu'en termes de [nutrition et d'impacts sur la santé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agriculture_biologique#Nutrition_et_sant%C3%A9) etc., l'efficacité des méthodes et les impacts de l'agriculture biodynamique **n'ont jamais été étayés indépendamment de ceux de la première, ni scientifiquement d'ailleurs**. [Conséquemment](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vin_biodynamique#Critiques) :

> Nombre de critiques reconnaissent la qualité des vins biodynamiques,
>   mais avancent que les améliorations constatées dans le goût du vin et
>   la santé du vignoble sont plus dues à un ensemble de bonnes pratiques
>   découlant de la simple reconversion en agriculture biologique et non
>   pas aux pratiques ésotériques ajoutées par la biodynamie. D'autres
>   spécialistes y ajoutent le travail méticuleux des viticulteurs qui
>   veillent à de nombreux détails souvent négligés. (Wikipédia)

Il est intéressant de noter par ailleurs que certaines des [réactions](https://www.agriculture-environnement.fr/2010/09/23/les-forces-cosmiques-de-la-biodynamie) (le regret de la disparition de la paysannerie, la réaction à l'introduction de la science en agriculture) à l'origine de l'agriculture biodynamique ne découlent pas de l'agriculture biologique mais en sont plutôt des [précurseurs](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agriculture_biologique#Les_origines_de_l'agriculture_biologique)...

---

En résumé le courant ésotérique de R. Steiner, le « contrôle des forces cosmiques » par l'entremise de préparations de *dynamisation* tout aussi ésotériques, ainsi que les références astrologiques la distingue de l'agriculture biologique et la définition au GDT est particulièrement inadéquate : il serait plus juste de parler de « l'action prétendue des astres et des phénomènes ésotériques ».